# How can I convert IList<object> to string array?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, telegram-bot

### How can I convert IList objects to string array?

While working on the telegram bot, some difficulties arose. I get a `IList<object>` from google table with some information. I need to convert this `IList<object>` to an array of strings. How can I do this?

```
static void ReadBudgetTypes()
{
    var range = $"{settingsSheet}!B3:B";
    var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);
    var response = request.Execute();
    var values = response.Values; // here i get list of objects from google table

    if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var row in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No data!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want this converted to `List<string>` or `List<string[]>`? The `row[0]` part confused me, if `row` is a string, why are you printing the first character of that string?

Comment: @RoyCohen. I want to convert `IList<object>` to `string[]`. `row[0]` means first column of this range `var range = $"{settingsSheet}!B3:B";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming cells may not be strings and may (or may not) have `null` values, you can print for each cell of the row:

```
// assumes ToString() gives a meaningful string
var listOfStrings = row.Select(x => x?.ToString()).ToList();
foreach(string cell in listOfStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(cell);
```

or the whole row, joined by a separator

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row);
```

If you know the cells are strings you can just cast

```
var listOfStrings = row.Cast<string>().ToList();
// or
var listOfStrings = row.Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
```

and then repeat either of the above (loop or `string.Join`).

If items could be `null`,

```
var listOfStrings = row.Select(x => (x ?? (object)"").ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: it compiles but console write `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`

Comment: Seems like you want to deal with individual cells. I'll update the answer to see if it matches your intention.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var tempList=List<string>();
string[] arrayList=null;
if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
 {
      foreach (var row in values)
      {
         tempList.Add(row[0]);
      }
   arrayList=tempList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    IList<object> list = new List<object>(){ "something", "something else" };
    string[] array = list.Select(item => (String)item).ToArray();
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0).

Comment: I was not familiar with that method, thanks!